# How to PATH pip from Spyder(anaconda3) to use in windows 10 command prompt

Tags: pip, path, windows-10, spyder, command-prompt

I use Spyder(anaconda3) to do much of my python work and I can use pip install directly from the spider console but not from windows 10 command prompt. Is there a way to PATH pip install from the spider/anaconda program to work directly with the command prompt?

Is this something that is strictly necessary or even useful to do, can the spider console handle all that is required (even non python instilations) without bothering with the windows comand prompt? For example if I were to run

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

from the spider console would this be an issue or would it make more sense to run it from the command prompt? (I know jupyterlab is included in annaconda I was just looking for an exapmle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between running the Windows command shell from Spyder is that Spyder will automatically activate your conda environment. You can achive the same thing by running

```
conda activate
```

as the first command in your Windows cmd shell.

Alternatively you can start the cmd shell via the "Anaconda prompt" in the Windows Start Menu.

Comment: Ok thank you, so there isn't much reason to use windows prompt over anaconda prompt then?